# iOS 6 Social framework Facebook with graph api not get posted

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios6, social-framework

I have created a Facebook app for my iOS application in Facebook developer console, but when I use that app id, even though I get the response as success it won't get posted. Please find below my code.(even I get the id for that particular post)

But the point is when I execute same code with my existing Facebook app id(Which is currently using for my live app), this get posted and works fine, so my assumption is, there is something I have to do in Facebook app configuration in the developer console, but I couldn't find. can anyone give me a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Note : I use iOS 6 social framwork

Get User method

```
    - (void)getUserAndShare {
    NSLog(@"Getting User");

    if(!_accountStore)
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                           options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if(granted){
                                                NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                                _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                                NSLog(@"Success account");

                                                [_accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:_facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error){

                                                    }

                                                    [self postPhoto:nil];
                                                }];


                                            }
                                        }];

}
```

Share method

```
-(IBAction)postPhoto{

    if(!_accountStore)
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"this is a resource picture 2", ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"};

    SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                              URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"]
                                                       parameters:parameters];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"sec.jpg"]);
    [facebookRequest addMultipartData: data
                             withName:@"source"
                                 type:@"multipart/form-data"
                             filename:@"msg.jpg"];

    facebookRequest.account = _facebookAccount;

    [facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) {
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Post successful");
             NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
             NSLog(@"Response Data: %@", dataString);
         }
     }];
}
```

Edit : Is it required to request special permission to use graph API when calling `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it working, and my assumption was correct :) I have to add new permission when i requesting the access. So as i said it worked in my previous Facebook app ID, thats because i have already granted the permission for that app. Anyway, for those who interest to see what is the solution, find it below,

```
 //Specify App ID and permissions
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };
```

Requested two new permissions `publish_stream` and `publish_actions`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your MIME type, issue in this line:

```
[facebookRequest addMultipartData: data
                             withName:@"source"
                                 type:@"multipart/form-data"
                             filename:@"msg.jpg"];
```

Change that to:

```
[facebookRequest addMultipartData:data
                       withName:@"media"
                           type:@"image/jpeg"
                       filename:@"msg.jpg"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, and if the code is wrong, how comes it work with another Facebook app ID?